# Is Using Multiprocessing to load files bad for my SSHD drive?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a script that uses the multiprocessing library to load data from files simultaneously.

My machine has a CPU with 8 cores and a Solid State Hybrid Drive.

I didn't expect any improvement, but have found that the multiprocessing version of the script is 3 times faster than the single process version (5 seconds vs 15 seconds). I presume this is because a lot of my files are compressed, so some of the "loading" time will actually be spent decompressing data.

Anyway, I am wondering, is this practice likely to be bad for my hardware? When I have done similar stuff in the past with normal hard drives it resulted in lots of disk thrashing. Though that does not seem to be the case on my SSHD drive.

As a second point, I find this syntax ugly:

```
def load_market( args):
    market_id, market = args
```

Is there a way to let me have a function signature of:

```
def load_market( market_id, market ):
    market_id, market = args
```

instead? At the moment I get this error if I try the 2nd version:

```
TypeError: load_market() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'market' and 'data'
```

An exerpt of my loading code is here:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def load_catalogues_mp( catalogue_stores ):
    result = {}
    for m, catalogue_store in catalogue_stores.items():
        print( m, catalogue_store )
        market_series = load_catalogue_mp( catalogue_store )
        result.update( market_series )
    return result

def load_catalogue_mp( catalogue_store ):
    num_pools = mp.cpu_count()
    pool      = mp.Pool( num_pools )
    inputs    = [ ( market_id, market ) for market_id, market in catalogue_store.items() ]
    cms_list  = pool.map( load_market, inputs )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return dict( zip( catalogue_store.market_ids, cms_list ) )

def load_market( args):#market_id, market, data ):
    market_id, market = args
    cms = mod.CompactMarketSeries( market )
    cms.load()
    return cms

with Timer( 'Loading catalogues' ) as t:
    market_series = load_catalogues_mp( catalogue_stores )
print( 'loaded catalogues' )
```

Comment: Please don't put two (or more) unrelated questions into the one post: it makes it less useful for future readers.

Comment: Ginger, if you put the Python part in a separate question, I will happily answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, multiprocessing with a mechanical hard-drive can result in thrashing, but despite the name, it isn't "bad" for the drive; it is just slower.

A SSHD cannot thrash by its nature.  It lacks the read-arm whose motion back-and-forth constitutes thrashing.

It is the same reason your turtle cannot get gray hair as it gets older.

Answer (score 2):

Using multiprocessing with SSHD is not bad at all, actually it's one of the reasons why SSHD drives are so much used nowadays. Using multiprocessing with SSHD is almost like using multiprocessing with your RAM memory : this type of memory will handle it very well.

With older hard drives, especially if you used a VPS, you could have a lot of `EOF` errors.
That's why SSHD are far more powerful than classic hard drives.

Comment: But unless the data is in the SS part of the drive, won't it use the HD part?

Comment: "There is no dark side of the moon: it's all dark."  An SSHD is 100% solid-state; there is no mechanical disk.

Comment: An SSHD is a hybrid drive:

http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/solutions/solid-state-hybrid/

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by a few other users, SSDs are fundamentally different from traditionall HDDs.  HDDs consist of rotating magnetic platters and read/write heads positioned very close to the platters.  The heads are extended and retracted across the radius of the platters to select different tracks.  The time required to move the heads to the desired track is known as seek time.  In addition, once the head arrives at the desired track it needs to wait for the platter to rotate to the desired sector.  This delay is known as seek latency.  The combination of seek time and latency make HDDs best suited to sequential I/O patterns because less head movement is required.  Although it depends on your end-to-end design, this is where multiprocessing has the potential to reduce HDD performance.  It will be difficult to maintain a sequenial I/O pattern across multiple processes.

On the other hand, SSDs are a memory device and there is no penalty for random access since there are no mechanical devices to be moved around.  Everything moves at the speed of light.  Writes to SSDs are a bit different because only erased sectors can be written and sectors can only be erased in groups.  Writes to unerased sectors require an entire group of sectors to be read, modified, and re-written.